# Discord API. exception error on on_member_remove()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(
                          messages = True, 
                          guilds = True, reactions = True, 
                          members = True, presences = True
                          )
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "[", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} is ___")
    


@bot.event
async def on_member_remove():
    print("xxx")
    if member.id == 341212492212600832:
        invitelink = discord.TextChannel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
        await member.send(f"you ___ bro. Here u go {inviteLink}")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Ignoring exception in on_member_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Filbert\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_remove() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 3):

As the error said, `on_member_remove` takes 1 positional argument `member`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member): # You forgot to pass it
    # ...
```

#### Reference:

- [`on_member_remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `on_member_join`, `on_member_remove` gets passed `member`, as said in [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_remove). After fixing this issue, regenerate your token, as you included it in the original post.
Another issue: You shouldn't be creating an instance of discord.TextChannel. Instead, get that channel using `bot.get_channel(id)`, and call `create_invite` on the TextChannel instance that `get_channel` returns.